# Unable to get words to simply wrap without breaking

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with getting a long paragraph of words to wrap to the next line *without* them breaking at all, even with hyphens.

My code:

```
p {
     white-space: pre-wrap !important;
     word-wrap: normal !important;
     word-break: normal !important;
     overflow-wrap: normal !important;
}
```

On Chrome, the word wrap works fine. No hyphens, just beautiful word-wrap with WHOLE words. On Firefox and Edge, I get word-wrap with HYPHENS, cutting up words between two lines.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if maybe you have other code thats conflicting with the p tags. because, what i'm finding is that your code:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

is the only place your changing from the default, which by default words dont wrap.

Maybe provide us with some more of your code, if possible.

Comment: It's at the bottom of my styles sheet. This is a wordpress install, modified 2013 theme. AFAIK, an `!important` override should override a previous `!important`, right?

Comment: Additionally, if I inspect a `p` element in Firefox (one place it's breaking), it shows that the `white-space: pre-wrap`; is not being overridden or canceled out.

Comment: a style with !important will override all others styles. But then if you have multiple !important's it can get tricky trying to track down what exactly is happening, I try to use them very sparingly. Here's a good write up about it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

Dang it. Stupid answer:

`hyphens: none; -webkit-hyphens: none;`

I can't believe I didn't think of this earlier.